# Sampling in Compressed sensing: How can one sample $y_i$ be a linear combination of the sampled signal $x$

Tags: signal-processing, sampling-theory

In the article *Compressive sensing* by Richard Baraniuk ($2007$), measurements are formulated as:
$$\mathbf{y} = \Phi \mathbf{x} = \Phi \Psi \mathbf{s} $$
Where $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are measurements of a signal, $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the signal sampled in time domain, $\mathbf{s}\in \mathbf{R}^n$ is the coefficients of the signal represented in some basis $\Psi \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a random Gaussian measurement matrix mapping measurements to the signal.

My questions are:

- Assuming we are sampling a signal $\mathbf{x}$ with one sensor. How is it possible that the mapping $\Phi$ between the measurements $\mathbf{y}$ and the signal sampled $\mathbf{x}$ is nothing more than a binary matrix with maximum one non-zero value for each row of $\Phi$ so that each element of $\mathbf{y}$ correspond to one element of $\mathbf{x}$, so that the measurement is an actual value of the signal $\mathbf{x}$?
  In other words, given a random Gaussian measurement matrix $\Phi$, how can one sample of the signal actually be a random linear combination of several values of the signal, and how do we know when the measurement is sampled form the signal $\mathbf{x}$

R. G. Baraniuk, "Compressive Sensing [Lecture Notes]," in IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, vol. 24, no. 4, pp. 118-121, July 2007, doi: 10.1109/MSP.2007.4286571.

Comment: Related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628693/calculating-an-incoherence-property/640419#640419).

Answer (score 1):

I was taught that we should think of the sensing matrix as an experimental tool that a practitioner can *choose*. Each row of the matrix corresponds to a single experiment, or measurement. Each of these experiments can be designed by the practitioner. What if, instead of using a binary matrix -- which is just observing the superposition of a few entries of $x$ either "on" or "off" -- we just take a random linear combination of them? It turns out that this experimental setup (using a random matrix) actually has some really exceptional properties; they are almost always better than a deterministically-chosen binary matrix. Since the practitioner can choose what type of experiments they want to perform, it makes sense to pick a matrix from this class.

Comment: Ok, but how do we then know when the measurements $y_i$ are sampled from the signal $\mathbf{x}$. If we use a linear combination of entries in $\mathbf{x}$ in each measurement?

Comment: @Erlend I'm not sure I understand the question. Usually each $y_i$ is equal to a linear combination of the components of $x$, and the practitioner gets to decide beforehand which linear combination to use. Usually if you choose those coefficients randomly, you get some nice theoretical properties.

Comment: Imagine we have a 1D signal in $\mathbf{x}$ in time domain.  I mean that the samples $y_i$ must have be taken taken of the signal right? If that is the case, we have to know when in terms of index of the $\mathbf{x}$ signal to sample the signal so that the mapping $\Phi$ from $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{x}$ is correct?

Comment: Remember that $\mathbf{x}$ are not the coefficients in this case, $\mathbf{s}$ are. $\mathbf{x}$ is the signal as a function of time

Comment: Yes, each entry of $y$ is a linear combination of the components of $x$ with coefficients determined by the rows of $\Phi$. Also, we know which components of $x$ are used to construct each entry of $y$. In practice, the rows of $\Phi$ are randomly generated and stored before the experiment occurs. so we know what the coefficients (entries of $\Phi$) are.

Comment: @Erlend this model kindof assumes that $y$ was observing for the entire duration. Instead of storing every single value of $x$ in $y$(which is expensive), it just adds up a linear combination of each entry in a small number of different ways. Each entry $y_j$ is updated at every timestep as $x$ is being observed. The update is processed by adding the coefficient (determined by $\Phi$) multiplied by the entry of $x$ at that particular time. This results in the final linear combination at the end of the process.

Comment: Ok, so in the case of expensive measurements, where we only have access to $\mathbf{x}$ at few time instants, the measurement matrix $\Phi$ cannot be a dense matrix populated with random numbers?

Comment: Yeah, I'd imagine so! The Gaussian stuff is more when storage is the main concern, and sampling the signal is (more or less) constant cost. This allows the compression $y$ to be stored in a much smaller space than $x$. However, yes, if you add the constraint that $\Phi$ can not be dense (due to measurement costs), then you shouldn't/can't use randomly generated entries of $\Phi$.