# What is a sampling matrix? How do I construct one?

Tags: matrices, information-theory, signal-processing, sampling, sampling-theory

I am reading [this page](http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python) on Compressed Sensing.  I quoted maybe more than I needed to for context.  Knowledgeable people might want to skip to the end of the quote and read backwards.

> You might be asking: what the hell is that $A$ matrix? Well, it’s the key to the whole party. Let me explain. 
>  In order to perform the minimization, we must somehow finagle our problem into a linear system of equations: $$Ax=b$$ Specifically, we want to derive a matrix $A$ that can be multiplied with a solution candidate $x$ to yield $b$, a vector containing the data samples. In the context of our current problem, the candidate solution x exists in the frequency domain, while the known data b exists in the temporal domain. Clearly, the matrix performs both a sampling and a transformation from spectral to temporal domains. 
>  Compressed sensing really comes down to being able to correctly derive the $A$ operator. Fortunately, there’s a methodology. Start off by letting $f$ be the target signal in vector form (if your signal is $2$-dimensional or higher, flatten it) and $\Phi$ be the sampling matrix. Then: $$b=\Phi f$$

---

I tried Google, but thanks to the stemming of words ("sample" vs "sampling") and different definitions of the word "matrix", I can't find a good link.

How do I construct a sampling matrix?

Comment: Suppose that you have a small black & white image. Say, 100 x 100 pixels. Suppose that you want to measure the blackness / whiteness for the pixel in the northwest corner. You take the inner product of that image with a  sampling matrix that has a single $1$ in the northwest corner and ($100^2 -1 $ in total) $0$s elsewhere. This is a somewhat boring sampling matrix. In general, you could "measure" a "mix" of pixel values. Say, the average of all four corners pixel values.

Comment: So a sampling matrix is a matrix with only zeros and ones were the ones "turn on" the pixel(s) in question?

Comment: No. Those would be binary sampling matrices. For example, in [this](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/software/l1magic/downloads/papers/StableRecovery.pdf) very famous paper, the sampling matrix is a Gaussian random matrix. Note that the output of this sampling is not a matrix, but a scalar. Another boring sampling matrix would be the one that takes the average of all pixel values. Imagine that you generate "many" random sampling matrices, thereby obtaining many real-valued measurements. One goal could be to reconstruct the original image from these measurements.

Comment: Terence Tao, [Compressed sensing and single-pixel cameras](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/compressed-sensing-and-single-pixel-cameras), April 13, 2007.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/640419/339790